# Squared magnitude of two complex numbers

Tags: complex-numbers

I believe one easy questions for maths experts. If I have two complex numbers x=a+ib and y=c+di is the squared magnitude of their sum equal to:
\begin{equation}
|x+y|^2=|x|^2+2|xy|+|y|^2
\end{equation}

Comment: Hint: take $x=1$ and $y=-1$.

Answer (score 2):

Hint:

Consider the case $y=-x \ne 0$.

Comment: So I assume equation that I have written is ok.

Comment: @Cali Don't assume when you can _check yourself_. Insert and calculate, see what you get.

Comment: @Cali: if you substitute $y=-x$ in your equation  you can easily see that it's wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Your LHS equals
$$
(a+c)^2+(b+d)^2=(a^2+b^2)+2(ac+bd)+(c^2+d^2)=|x|^2+2(ac+bd)+|y|^2
$$
so it's almost the RHS, except for the fact that
\begin{aligned}
2|xy|&=2|(ab-cd)+i(ac+bd)|=2\sqrt{(ab-cd)^2+(ac+bd)^2}\\
&=2\sqrt{a^2b^2+c^2d^2+a^2c^2+b^2d^2}\\
&\neq 2(ac+bd).
\end{aligned}
In fact,
$$
(ac+bd)^2=a^2c^2+b^2d^2+2(ab)\cdot (cd)\leq a^2b^2+c^2d^2+a^2c^2+b^2d^2.
$$
So in fact you have LHS $\leq$ RHS, not LHS $=$ RHS.

Answer (score 1):

$$
\begin{align}
|x+y|^2 & = (x+y)(\bar x + \bar y) \\
 & = x \bar x + x \bar y + \bar x y + y \bar y \\
 & = |x|^2 + |y|^2 + 2 \operatorname{Re} (x \bar y) \\
 & = |x|^2 + |y|^2 + 2 |x y| \cos \theta \\
 & \ne |x|^2 + |y|^2 + 2 |x y| \quad \text{unless the angle between} \;x,y \;\text{is}\;\theta=0
\end{align}
$$

Comment: that means if $y=\bar{x}$, i.e. y is conjugated complex version of x, in that case my initial equality would hold?

Comment: @Cali I fixed the post above, that was meant to be the angle between $x,y$. If $y = \lambda x$ with $\lambda \in \mathbb{R}^+$ then the equality holds.

Comment: So in the case of conjugate complex if would essentially have that |$x$+$\bar{x}$|^2=($x$+$\bar{x}$)($\bar{x}$+${x}$)=($x$+$\bar{x}$)^2? or I am wrong again?

Comment: @Cali $x+\bar x \in \mathbb{R}$ and $|r|^2 = r^2$ for $\forall r \in \mathbb{R}$.